# adding linux mysql record from windows, 0xae is confusing things

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using codeignighter and

Trying to import a record, that contains a circle R in it (hex 0xae)

My codeignigher database config  is setup for

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

my mysql database column is a varchar

I'm getting an error

```
Incorrect string value: '\xAE, CPC...' for column `compul6_mobileca`.`Agency`.`agency` at row 1
```

I thought 0xae was utf8, and varchar is 1 byte chars.

So I have no idea why it's complaining. Looking for a general solution for any other strangeness in the file (that is re-generated frequently so modify the file isn't an option).

Comment: Beyond basic ASCII there are no single-byte characters in UTF-8. That input is likely ISO-8859-1 or cp1252 and you need to convert it. https://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding

Comment: Additionally none of the text types [eg: `VARCHAR`] have anything to do with how many bytes each character is composed of, that would be the domain of the charset defined on the table or column. Even so, Mysql frequently won't stop you from cramming in text data with mismatched encodings, as there's no reliable way to actually detect an encoding, and you likely won't notice until well down the line when you see so corrupted text output.

Comment: Big thank you for your help! That got it working.

Comment: @Sammitch why don't you convert your 2 comments into an answer? or point to a known duplicate?